# Pyyaml, accessing dictionary in Python

Tags: python, pyyaml

I have some yaml I'm trying to access keys in python.

```
---
nodes:
-
  AAAA: AAAA
  BBBB: BBBB
  CCCC: CCCC
  DDDD:
    AAAA: AAAA
    BBBB: AAAA
    CCCC: CCCC
-
  AAAA: AAAA
  BBBB: BBBB
  CCCC: CCCC
  DDDD:
    AAAA: AAAA
    BBBB: AAAA
    CCCC: CCCC
```

I'm trying to access using the following python format.

```
import yaml
filepath = "report.yml"
audit = yaml.load(open(filepath))

audit['nodes']['DDDD'].items()
```

but I get the following error.

**print audit['nodes']['DDDD'].items()
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str**

Whats i'm expetcting to see is a list of key/values returned under DDDD

Obviously, I'm mixing up lists and dicts, but I don't quite see how... is it the yaml, python or my understanding of how pyyaml nests dicts in dicts?

Comment: `audit['nodes']` is a list

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have a list of nodes. Use a for-loop to access each node and then the required values

**Ex:**

```
import yaml
filepath = filename
audit = yaml.load(open(filepath))

for node in audit['nodes']:
    print( node['DDDD'].items() )
```

**Output:**

```
[('AAAA', 'AAAA'), ('CCCC', 'CCCC'), ('BBBB', 'AAAA')]
[('AAAA', 'AAAA'), ('CCCC', 'CCCC'), ('BBBB', 'AAAA')]
```